# Android disable a screen element but not have a gap

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

If i set a Screen element to be invisible in a "LinearLayout", i do anyway have a gap instead of it. How to make gap a disappear along with a element?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set view to **invisible** then your `View` will be still there just disappears but occupies its space while you use **gone** this will remove your view

this will solve your problem

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the "Visible" attribute to "Gone" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [view.setVisibility(View.GONE)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)